# Understanding Pathloss and latency

Tags: digital-communications, fading-channel, multipath

In my class on wireless communication, I came across the following sentence:

> The round trip path-loss can be defined to include aspects such as
> attenuation and/or latency etc

Hence I am looking for relation between Pathloss, attenuation and/or latency.

Comment: Can you explain what your understanding of each is? They seem different to me: one is about gain / attenuation in amplitude, the other is about difference / delay in time.

Comment: Need more information.  Yes, they're both related to distance.  But in general the independent factors affecting them have a far stronger effect than the effect of distance, so -- again in general -- any relationship between them is weak.  If there is something **specific** that you are asking about, then please _edit your question_ to include that.

Comment: @ peter @ Tim Thank you so much sir for your reply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible ways to model path loss to include both attenuation and delay (latency).  For example, this page from [Molisch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470741864) gives a way to include both: the Power Delay Profile approach.

[image: Page from Molisch]

Comment: Thank you so much sir...will go through it.

Comment: Sir, Since PDP (Path loss) and delay are directly proportional to each other, can we say that as Pathloss increases , delay increases?

Comment: @chaaru For the same path / channel, yes there will be a correlation. For different paths, with different attenuations, obviously the relation will be different.